# Identify in what of the given ranges is a random number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have this table with the first column being just an Identifier Code and the second one being the ranges.

[image]

So for example if a number is between 0 and 1134, it corresponds to the first row '1310101'. If it is between 1135 and 1311236 it corresponds to the second row, and so on and so forth.

I want to generate a random number in excel with `RANDBETWEEN(1,6551654)` and then identify in which range of the column 'Range' is the number, and return the identifier code. So if I get for example 1000, I want some function that return 1310101, because I don't want to specify the conditions manually (my table has 2000+ rows).

Comment: Just a format thing but can you please add the image through SU instead of sending us to tinypic? Many users don't want to visit an external site to see an image. Also my work blocks tinypic.

Comment: I can't post images because I don't have enough reputation, If you can tell me a way to add it, I'll do it. Edit: Someone did it, thanks to him/her!

Comment: Sorry, I tried but like I said my company blocked it. Thanks nixda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem presents two challenges.  First, VLOOKUP would typically be used for this general type of lookup, but it searches in the leftmost column of the range.  Second, the lookup functions, like VLOOKUP and MATCH, look for the largest value that is less than or equal to the target, which puts you in the wrong interval if it is not an exact match to the interval boundary.  One solution is to use the combination of INDEX and MATCH to freely choose the columns, plus a workaround for the interval selection.

Say your list of output values is in column D.  The formula requires multiple references to the same random value, so we need to use column C to create the value that will be used.  In as many cells in column C as you need, paste:

```
    =RANDBETWEEN(1,6551654)
```

The formula in D2 would be:

```
    =INDEX(A$2:A$7,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,B$2:B$7)),0,MATCH(C2,B$2:B$7))+IF(ISERROR((MATCH(C2,B$2:B$7,0))),1,0))
```

Copy that down column D for as many as you need.  I wrote the formula this way for the benefit of people using a spreadsheet like LibreOffice Calc, which lacks the IFERROR function.  For Excel, you can simplify the first ISERROR expression:

```
    IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,B$2:B$7)),0,MATCH(C2,B$2:B$7))   would become:
    IFERROR(MATCH(C2,B$2:B$7),0)
```

INDEX selects the value from the first column (I'm assuming column A), based on the MATCH results.  The first MATCH result is a normal lookup, with a correction in case the value is less than the first interval boundary.  The second MATCH result bumps it to the next interval if it is not an exact match to the boundary.